# String Replacement Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex, string, gsub

I need to replace a string of characters with a sequence; I am using the gsub method

Say,

`name = "Tom"`

and this appears in a text as `$(name)` i need to replace `$(name) with Tom`.

Now, it is replacing only `name` with `Tom` and not `$(name)` with `Tom`. Can you tell me how the gsub will be like.

Comment: Show your gsub, perhaps? Also, why do you replace `name` and not `$(name)`?

Comment: The my_hash contains the name =>Tom correspondence. The gsub is as line.gsub($2 , my_hash). I get $2 from the regex that gives me "name"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I need to replace $(name). now the output I am getting is $(Tom),  not only Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to properly escape things:

```
string = "My name is $(name)"

string.gsub(/\$\(name\)/, "Tom")
# => My name is Tom
```

Of course you can easily make this more generic:

```
substs = {
  name: "Tom"
}

string.gsub(/\$\((\w+)\)/) do |s|
  substs[$1.to_sym]
end
```

Comment: Hi, Can you show me an implementation of your second code. I am very new to ruby and would like to know how to use it

Comment: You mean an explanation? That's a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that captures word-like values (`\w+`) and uses that to look-up in a Hash what to replace it with. That can be a lot to take in at first, but take it bit by bit and you'll come to understand it better. Techniques like this can do a lot of work with very little code. If you've got a good Ruby reference, that helps considerably.

Answer (score 2):

```
str.gsub('$(name)', 'Tom')
```

or, with a regexp

```
str.gsub(/\$\(name\)/, 'Tom')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "and this appears in a text as $(name) i need to replace $(name) with Tom."
str.tr!("$()","%{}") # use ruby's sprintf syntax %{name}
some_name = "Tom"

p str % {name: some_name}
# => "and this appears in a text as Tom i need to replace Tom with Tom."
```

Comment: That is a clever approach, though hopefully no `%{...}` content was present in the original.

Comment: thanks, but i don't think i will be able to use this as i am not aware in the data i will be parsing if i may encounter a `%{...}`